# Rails - why does this before_save trigger on create but not update?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

My model has:

```
class Link < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :group
  validates_presence_of :url_address
  validates_presence_of :group_id
  before_save :verify_url
  acts_as_list

  def valid_get?
    HTTParty.get(url_address).code.between?(100,399) ? true : false
  rescue SocketError, URI::InvalidURIError
    false
  end 

  def verify_url
    if valid_get?
      verified_date = Time.now
    end 
  end 

end
```

The verified_date gets set correctly to today's date when I create a record through the form.

Why doesn't the field get updated for an update of the record?

Controller:

```
class LinksController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :authorize, :except => [:index, :show, :advanced_search]

  ...

  def verify_link # Used by js. works fine to update the field.
    @link = Link.find(params[:id])
    if @link.valid_get?
      if @link.update_attribute(:verified_date, Time.now)
        render nothing: true, status: 200
      else
        render nothing: true, status: 422
      end
    else
      render nothing: true, status: 422
    end
  end

  def create # Used via the HTML form.  method should update verified_date but doesn't
    @link = Link.new(params[:link])
    @link.content_date = Time.new().strftime("%m/%d/%Y") if @link.content_date.nil?
    if @link.valid_get?
      @link.verified_date = Time.new()
      http_check_msg = 'and the url was verified as valid'
    else
      http_check_msg = 'however it was *not* possible to visit the url as given currently'
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      if @link.save
        flash[:notice] = 'Link was successfully created, ' + http_check_msg
        format.html { redirect_to(@link) }
      else
        flash[:notice] = 'Error, The link was not created.'
        @groups = Group.all.collect { |g| [g.group_name, g.id] }
        format.html { render :action => "new"}
      end
    end
  end
```

I have javascript which updates that field through the above controller verify_link method but the regular form and accompanying update method do not seem to be updating the attribute in the update method -

```
  def update
    @link = Link.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @link.update_attributes(params[:link])
        @link.verify_url
        @link.save
        flash[:notice] = 'Link was successfully updated.'
        format.html { redirect_to(@link.group) }
      else
        @groups = Group.all.collect { |g| [g.group_name, g.id] }
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
      end 
    end 
  end
```

Comment: What do your logs look like when the update action runs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your method to:

```
  def verify_url
    if valid_get?
      self.verified_date = Time.now
    end 
  end
```

Note the `self.`. Without the `self` you create a new local variable instead of changing the models attribute.

Comment: Great catch!  This is a common mistake, one I have made too many times I want to admit :)